# Styled-components not exporting

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Error:
./src/card.js
Attempted import error: 'Bottom' is not exported from './styles/cards.style'.

card.js

```
import React from 'react'

import {
  Bottom,
  Color,
  Text,
  Image
} from "./styles/cards.style";

function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Bottom>
        <Color />
        <Text>{props.text}</Text>
        <Text>{props.text}</Text>
      </Bottom>
      <Image
        alt=""
        src={props.image}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

cards.style

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export default {
  colors: {
    black: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
    brandPrimary: "rgba(238,120,36,1)",
    brandPrimaryLight: "rgba(255,184,8,1)",
    brandTertiary: "rgba(0,65,125,1)",
    darkSlateGray: "rgba(51,51,51,1)",
    white: "rgba(255,255,255,1)"
  },
  fonts: {
    uiMainContent: {
      family: "Poppins",
      size: "15px",
      weight: "300",
      lineHeight: "21px"
    },
    uiSubContent: {
      family: "Poppins",
      size: "13px",
      weight: "300",
      lineHeight: "20px"
    }
  }
};

export const Bottom = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.white};
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: relative;
`;
export const Color = styled.div`
  height: 120px;
  background-color: ${props =>
    props.theme.colors.brandPrimary};
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  align-self: stretch;
`;
export const Text = styled.p`
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.black};
  margin-left: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
  font-family: ${props =>
    props.theme.fonts.uiSubContent.family};
  font-size: ${props =>
    props.theme.fonts.uiSubContent.size};
  font-weight: ${props =>
    props.theme.fonts.uiSubContent.weight};
  line-height: ${props =>
    props.theme.fonts.uiSubContent.lineHeight};
  &:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
  }
`;
export const Image = styled.img`
  width: 150px;
  height: 92px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 29px;
  top: 14px;
`;
```

I am trying to build cards in reactjs. I usually stick to scss however cannot use props with scss which I will have to use later to dynamically generate components. Not sure what is wrong here as I did export Button. Please can someone shed some insight you see what is so blatantly wrong it is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

in that case you have an `export default` as the first thing of you code, if you are exporting more than one thing from the same file, you should stick to exporting each const/function by itself and not having any export default

If you are using ReactJS/NextJS I would really recommend creating a global theme that you normally write and import with the application, so you could have things like

```
// global.js
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  :root {
    --black: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    --brandPrimary: rgba(238,120,36,1);
    ...

  ...
`
}
```

Take a look [here](https://scalablecss.com/styled-components-global-styles/), it should help you a lot.